# What is the best way to convert List <string> to List<type> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I'm writing because I did not find a solution to my problem.
I have something like this:

```
private class MockClass
{
    public List<XClass> xList { get; set; }
}

private class XClass
{
    public XClass(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string Name{ get; }
}
```

Next, I have a method which takes a `List<string>`, and I want to convert this `List<string>` to a list like this:

```
private void CreateRequest(List<string> listOfString)
{
    var request = new MockClass
    {
        xList = // here I have no idea if this can be done
    };
}
```

Is there any point in doing so or just change  to string in the MockClass class?

Comment: `xList = listOfStrings.Select(x => new XClass(x)).ToList()`

Comment: What have you tried to do? Please show us *your* attempt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using linq:

```
xList = listOfString.Select(a => new XClass(a)).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Use the linq `Enumerable.Select` extension method, passing a `Func<string, XClass>` selector. The selector will convert each element of `listOfString` from a `string` to an instance of `XClass`. The result will be an `IEnumerable<XClass>`, which you convert to a `List<XClass>` by calling `ToList()`.

Comment: `var` would be excluded. It's a property of `MockClass` so it's already declared.

Comment: An explanation would be great to support your answer as well as give explanation to the OP...

Comment: Edited with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The [`List.ConvertAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall) method can be used to convert the list items :

```
xList = listOfString.ConvertAll(name => new XClass(name));
```